# Export followed by Import producing "0.e1" numbers

Tags: export, precision-and-accuracy

I had a large table of data that I exported, and then when it had completed, I exported it to a file. (Just in the form `Export["filename.dat", data]`, no specified format.). When I imported it later, I was confused by how much of it was 0's. Opening up the table, I saw the following chunks of data:

> 0.000999315368 0.00103971193 ... 0.001184 0.00112 0.00116 ... 0.0008 0.0007 0.e-3 ... 0. 0.e1 0.e1 0.e1 0.e2

Can anyone explain what this `0.e-3` format means? Why did my data export this way? The original was entirely nonzero.

Comment: Please post a snippet of the data, so that we can try to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I will if/when I can, but it was the result of a very long computation that will take a while to reproduce (a day or so of running; 12GB of RAM usage). Similar calculations with different parameters hadn't caused this behavior, either, so I wouldn't know how to get a minimal example case. I'll have to re-run the calculation anyway to get the data, so at that point I can post it here. Until then, I was hoping someone knew what sorts of values could produce the above output.

Comment: I can't at first glance reproduce `0.e-3` or similar. I suspect it has to do with some floating point precision issues. In general, `x.yyy e z` (spaces inserted for clarity) means `x.yyy*10^z`. Exporting a number like `0.00000005` would result in `5.e-8` though. As for `Import` issues, it may help to specify the format of the data being imported, e.g. `Import["filename.dat", "Table"]`

Comment: use `.m` format to preserve exact precision

Comment: Ah, thank you! :) That might come in handy. I've decided I'll just redo everything with 3 times the precision value, now. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be, as LLIAMNnYP suggested, a precision issue. The data I had contained values such as (in FullForm)

```
List[0``2.7745530926768973,0.0012428756482861055723647403237208664`0.33865082835168153,0``3.1320806025128776,0``3.1262338523773163,0.00272972783712194166621690533274311041`0.3781937081269392,0.00079422012197691538097255940529751282`1.0511881767729303,0``2.9372865212434487,0``2.5786797291683388,0``3.4913067025680555,0``3.4050525516996344,0``1.7137742939876988,0``3.210012647512957,0.00099100731685927050465534371426201687`0.03446455280318874,0.00107842029005569529455873228047266261`0.9198460804579403,0.00028526377555515141379652299669089643`0.06306105024607492,0``2.643792350067955,0``1.336393802620609,0``1.4768850172897074,0``2.91781013108647,0``3.1781825229994505,0.00186446416359446377421552474072804984`0.9610361487083864,0``2.743632616359945]`
```

where -- today I learned! -- the numbers after the double-backticks indicate uncertainty in the value. When it has this much uncertainty, the number itself renders as `0.*10^-4`, etc. When exported these became `0.eN`, when imported these were just a normal `0.0`.

Comment: Always +1 for self-answers